# Error in using getLine() in C++

Tags: c++

I just had this little problem, when I finished entering details for "Student No.1", and when it to the second one, it skips the name. Any help?
Here's my code so far:

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main(){

    int age[3];
    double gpa[3];
    string name[3], level[3];

    cout<<"< < < < < Enter 3 Student Data > > > > >"<<endl;
    for (int x=0; x<3; x++){
    cout<<"-------------------------------"<<endl;
    cout<<"Student No."<<x+1<<endl;
    cout<<"Enter name: ";
    getline(cin, name[x]);
    cout<<"Enter your age: ";
    cin>>age[x];
    cout<<"Enter your GPA: ";
    cin>> gpa[x];
    do{
    cout<<"Enter you grade level [freshman, sophomore, junior, or senior]: ";
    cin>>level[x];
    }while(level[x] != "freshman" && level[x] != "sophomore" && level[x] != "junior" && level[x] != "senior");
    cout<<"-------------------------------"<<endl;
    }

    system("pause");
    cout<<endl<<endl<<"< < < < < Enter 3 Student Datas > > > > >"<<endl;
    for (int x=0; x<3; x++){
    cout<<"-------------------------------"<<endl;
    cout<<"Name: "<<name[x]<<endl<<"Age: "<<age[x]<<endl<<"GPA: "<<gpa[x]<<endl<<"Level: "<<level[x];
    cout<<endl<<"-------------------------------"<<endl;
    //system ("pause");
    }
    return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mix cin and getline usage you have to remember that cin usually leaves \n character in keyboard buffer. When getline checks buffer it see \n character as first and immediately ends. Use cin.ignore before getline function to remove \n character.

Comment: i tried to do this but when it comes to printing, it skips the first letter of the name of the first record. Let's say i put King Garrett on the name, then it will display only "ing Garrett"

Comment: Call `cin.ignore(1 ,'\n');` as the last command inside first for loop and everything should work just fine.

Comment: it's still the same man. i put cin.ignore(); before the getline(), then i put cin.ignore(1,'\n'); on the last part of the first for loop but its still the same

Comment: Do not put cin.ignore() before the getline(). Just only put cin.ignore(1,'\n'); as the last part of the first for loop. Then it works, I checked that. In the answer by saying `Use cin.ignore before getline function to remove \n character` I didn't mean to put it directly in the line before getline() line. I meant to put it somewhere before next call to getline() function. In your case this is the end of first for loop.